# Azure Bicep returns "Unable to restore the module with reference "br:bicep/modules/network.virtual-network:1.0.0""

Tags: azure-bicep

I'm trying to create resources using Bicep but I'm not sure about using these two types. Some people use resource keyword to directly create resources and other get the modules from the the below azure repo - https://github.com/Azure/ResourceModules/blob/main/modules/compute/virtual-machine/README.md.

When I try to use the below code snippet for VM from Azure repo it throws the below error, could you please first explain what the module line is doing because my understanding of module is that I'm supposed to put the parent module/file location I want to use after the symbolic name but I'm not sure what this BR line doing?

Error:

> Error BCP192: Unable to restore the module with reference "br:bicep/modules/network.virtual-network:1.0.0": Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (bicep:443)) (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (bicep:443)) (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (bicep:443)) (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (bicep:443))

Code:

```
module virtualMachine 'br:bicep/modules/compute.virtual-machine:1.0.0' = {
  name: '${uniqueString(deployment().name, location)}-test-cvmwinmin'
  params: {
    // Required parameters
    adminUsername: adminusername
    imageReference: {
      offer: 'WindowsServer'
      publisher: 'MicrosoftWindowsServer'
      sku: '2022-datacenter-azure-edition'
      version: 'latest'
    }
    nicConfigurations: [
      {
        ipConfigurations: [
          {
            name: 'ipconfig01'
            subnetResourceId: '<subnetResourceId>'
          }
        ]
        nicSuffix: '-nic-01'
      }
    ]
    osDisk: {
      diskSizeGB: '128'
      managedDisk: {
        storageAccountType: 'Premium_LRS'
      }
    }
    osType: 'Windows'
    vmSize: 'Standard_DS2_v2'
    // Non-required parameters
    adminPassword: '<adminPassword>'
    enableDefaultTelemetry: '<enableDefaultTelemetry>'
    location: '<location>'
    name: 'cvmwinmin'
  }
}
```

Comment: have you check the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/modules#public-module-registry ? It is pointing got another github repo: https://github.com/azure/bicep-registry-modules.

Comment: Vnet module can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/bicep-registry-modules/tree/main/modules/network/virtual-network

Comment: the module name are a bit different: `br/public:network/virtual-network:x.x.x`

Comment: Hi @Thomas - Thanks for your help. I have went through the documentation Could you please clarify my below statements, the line 'br:bicep/modules/compute.virtual-machine:1.0.0' refers to public registry right? if so do do think the reason why i'm getting the error is because i didn't include the  public keyword in the BR line ?

Comment: `br` stands for bicep registry. Registries are access like that: `br:<registry fqdn>`. `br/public` is the alias for `br:mcr.microsoft.com`.

Comment: See explanation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/modules#public-module-registry

Comment: so yeah the line `br:bicep/modules/compute.virtual-machine:1.0.0` is missing the `public` alias.